# How to read value from formula (in a unsaved excel file)

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I would like to automate a simple process to read some values from excel files with `openxlsx`

- First, I have an Excel file template, in which, let's say, there is a simple formula: the cell B1 will sum two cells A1 and A2
- Now I would like to create several Excel files from this template, and I will modify the value of the two cells A1 and A2. It is possible to do so with `loadWorkbook`, `writeData` and `saveWorkbook`
- From this list of excel files, I want now the value of B1. When using `read.xlsx`, it happens that the value of B1 is not correct; the correct value is only read if we open the Excel file and save it.

I think that the same issue happens when we try to use hyperlinks: in stead of R to read Excel files, we could use hyperlinks to get the cells from different Excel files. But after some research, I found that the files should also be opened.

So my question is: is there a function in `openxlsx` that can open an Excel file and evaluate the formula?

Comment: We can do this with the R packages XLConnect and RDCOMClient. If you want, I can provide examples.